# Segmentation fault(core dumped) when printing pointer's information

Tags: c, string, input, ncurses

I'm reading in my input and putting it in a pointer. I have used malloc so I'm not sure what wrong

CODE:

```
#define BUFFER 30 //in my .h file

char *inStr;
inStr = malloc(sizeof(char*)*BUFFER);
scanw("%s", &inStr);
inStr[strlen(inStr)] = '\0';
mvwprintw(stdscr, 0, 0, "%s",inStr);
```

I'm trying to output it onto a ncurses board and am not sure why this is happening. It crashes when I press enter for the input

Comment: What is `buffer`? What are it's contents? How do you know `malloc()` was successful? What gets put into `inStr`? Why even write `inStr[strlen(inStr)] = '\0';`

Comment: `sizeof(char*)`? What is `BUFFER`?

Comment: You malloc'ed something, alright. You're *sure* that `char*` shouldn't be `char` ? The fourth line seems completely useless, as `scanw` should terminate that string for you (how do you think `strlen` would work if it *didn't* ?). And this: `scanw("%s", &inStr);` should be `scanw("%s", inStr);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First item, for a "%s" format, you need to pass a pointer to a buffer.  You are actually passing a pointer to a pointer to a buffer.  Drop the &.  Second, strlen is defined by the presence of a null at the end, so using it to determine where to put a null is a bit nonsensical.  Instead, you have to trust scanw to terminate it properly.  Note that is a HUGE assumption and is a big part of why the whole scanf family is troubled by buffer overruns - the function has no idea how big the buffer is.  Also, as others point out, your malloc size is off - you probably just want something like `malloc(BUFFER)` - note sizeof(char) is 1 by definition.

```
char *inStr;
inStr = malloc(BUFFER);
scanw("%s", inStr);
mvwprintw(stdscr, 0, 0, "%s",inStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER)
```